# Dell PowerEdge 1600SC Server - Ethernet port semi-functional

Tags: fedora, dell, ethernet, dell-poweredge, networking

Dell PowerEdge 1600SC Server: First it had Fedora 12 with Amahi Home Server on it, then I installed Windows Server 2003 Standard on top of it.  The ethernet port worked for Fedora and Server 2003, but after a while, the port became non-functional - refusing to recognize ethernet cables...It simply regularly blinks a green light, whether a cable is plugged in or not.  I tested the cables on working connections and they work.

I then decided to go back to Fedora 12, so installed that again.  It still doesn't work...I've tinkered with settings in the BIOS, and the port recognizes the cable but doesn't provide LAN or Internet, *only* when the NIC is disabled and the IRQ set to a certain setting.  I've tried running `cat /proc/interrupts` in Fedora and choosing a IRQ that is not taken.

Can anyone tell me what is going on?  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the network port just died. Get yourself a gigabit network card such as a Intel Pro (even the desktop models are great) They have driver support for tons of Operating systems and tend to be just plug and play. Can get them cheap.

Comment: can I get any old PCI gigabit network card and install it?  Do you recommend any specific ones?

Comment: If you're not going to maximizing traffic, the above suggestion to get an Intel Pro adapter will be sufficient. You might consider getting one with two or more ports if this truly is a "server"

Comment: @studiohack: Yes just about any pci gigabit nic should work in your situation as most will work with modern operating systems. I just recommend the Intel Pro 1000 since they are rock solid and the support for them is great. They are cheap too (the desktop version and in your case I don't see why you would need a real server grade card) Your server appears to have 2x PCI 32 bit and 2x PCI 64bit so plenty of room. Spend a few bucks and your issues with networking shall be over :)